# OP being picky and choosy, a valid reason to close as "unclear what you're asking"?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, unclear

Here's a scenario I've seen played out a few times:

- OP asks a question, stating their problem clearly and unambiguously (so not close-able at first pass), and mentions several methods that the problem could be addressed
- Someone answers the question, using one of the methods mentioned in the original question as a possible solution that the OP was after
- OP suddenly decides that isn't good enough, and they are actually holding out for an even better answer

To me, this seems like they weren't being entirely honest with their requirements, they actually want X, but they pretend that Y is acceptable just to get people to contribute answers that they can use as a fall-back if no X is forthcoming.

Is this legit? It seems like an abuse of the good-will of answerers to me, they should state their requirements up front, and that way people are not lured into wasting their time contributing answers that are not going to be accepted.

Is it valid to vote to close such a question as "unclear what you're asking"?

Comment: Just roll it back to the original question and tell them to ask another question if they have one - that kind of bait-and-switch is not acceptable. If they're commenting on the answers, I'd be inclined to flag as not constructive.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with the OP deciding to delay accepting to wait for another, possibly better in their mind answer.

Comment: [SE Meta: Exit strategies for “chameleon questions”](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions).

Comment: It is a non-issue, you can always out-last a fussy questioner.  The OP has a job to finish, you can simply walk away.

Comment: @HansPassant You appear to be underestimating how addicted some users are to rep, and the lengths that they're willing to go to get a few Imaginary Internet Points.

Comment: @Servy rep isn't so important but wasting people's time by asking a question under false pretences is an issue in my opinion, if we assume that the time of answerers is worth something. There isn't an unaccepted answer of mine that is motivating this question either.

Comment: @samgak I'm not seeing anything here that indicates false pretenses.  It sounds like the OP simply doesn't feel a particular answer is a quality answer, and you disagree.  Not everything is always going to agree on the quality of answers.  That doesn't mean anyone is doing anything wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the OP is editing the question to change the requirements, then simply roll back the edit.  Completely changing the question to ask something else is not appropriate.  If the user is rolling back your change, or re-applying the edit, flag for moderator attention and explain the situation.

If the user isn't changing the question, and simply states that they don't like your answer, or would like to wait for a better one, *without changing their question* then they're doing nothing wrong at all. Just because you think a particular answer is good doesn't mean they're obligated to agree with you.